# Confirm code that returns nodes with two children

Tags: java

I was given the following code that is supposed to determine the number of nodes in a tree that have two children...

```
public int twoChildren(TreeNode<Integer> root){
    int counter= 0;
    if (root == null)
        return 0;
    else if (root.right != null && root.left != null)
        counter++;

    int leftTwoChildren = twoChildren(root.left);
    int rightTwoChildren = twoChildren(root.right);

    return counter + leftTwoChildren + rightTwoChildren;
}
```

My job is to identify if this code is doing that, and if it isn't then figure out what the issue is. It all seems to check out with me, but I just wanted to double check that the counter works on this example. Would I even need the two integers for the left and right? I'm not sure. If someone could confirm this checks out or let me know there's an issue I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will work fine if you return 0 instead of null

```
if(root==null)
   return 0;
```

You don't need the two integers for left and right, you can return the recursive calls explicitly, and also get rid of counter integer.

```
 public int twoChildren(TreeNode<Integer> root){

   if (root == null)
    return 0;

   if (root.right != null && root.left != null)
    return 1 + twoChildren(root.left) + twoChildren(root.right);

    return twoChildren(root.left) + twoChildren(root.right);
}
```

Comment: Okay but a quick question, the return in the second if includes a one because the would be the case where the root has two children then obviously we do the left then right. But why doesn't that final return statement include the 1? Also, the null was a typo it's supposed to be 0 :)

Comment: Because if the if statement returns false then the node doesn't have two children, in that case we don't want to count it, right?. but it could have one child and we have to continue calculating for it, but we don't count the parent, so the last return statement supposed to be 0 + twoChildren(root.left)+twoChildren(root.right), but zero has nothing to do here.

Comment: Ohhh so both returns won't go. It will either be the first if the root has two, or the second if it doesn't?

Comment: Yes, of course, no code is executed after return statement is executed

Comment: Alright thank you so much for taking the time to help me out!